# problem after migrating cakephp 1.2 to 1.3.2

Tags: migration, cakephp-1.3, dispatcher, cakephp-1.2

I upgrade cakephp 1.2 to 1.3.2 and I am having **Notice (8): Undefined variable: url [APP/webroot/index.php, line 88]**. does anybody know how can I sort it out?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you followed the guide for [migrating from CakePHP 1.2 to 1.3](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3)? One of the first things it says is to replace APP/webroot/index.php with the new version due to changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I made changes but still I am getting same notice